# PassportJS producing 500 failures using BasicStrategy

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I have installed `passport` and `passport-http`. 
I am trying to get my NodeJS Application to allow Basic Authentication, using express.

I have defined the following authentication function for testing purposes in `accessControl/users`:

```
var auth=function(user, callback){
    console.log("Checking Credentials for "+user)
    if (user === 'chuck') {
        var userObj = { name:'chuck' };
        userObj.validPassword = function(password) {
            return (password === 'testa');
        }
        callback(null, userObj);
    }
}
```

This my express route:

```
var express = require('express');
var users = require('../accessControl/users');
var passport = require('passport')
  , BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;

var router = express.Router();

passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
            function(username, password, done) {
                users.auth({ username: username  }, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) { return done(err);  }
                    if (!user) { return done(null, false);  }
                    if (!user.validPassword(password)) { return done(null, false);  }
                    return done(null, user);

                });

            }

            ));


router.get('/test',
    passport.authenticate('basic',{session:true}),
    function(req, res){
    //TODO
    res.render('index');
});
```

Accessing `/test` first gives me a Browser Login Prompt.
Entering chuck as Username and testa as password redirects to my 500 Error page although the file index.ejs exists in my views folder and is send when I comment out the passport.authenticate line.
Trying to log the produced error via app.js gave me `{}`.

EDIT: 
I am running the app with

`DEBUG=my-app node ./bin/www` inside a terminal

EDIT2:

I get the following output:

```
my-app Express server listening on port 3000
GET /test 401 18,4333 ms --
GET /test 500 29,882 ms -- 1905
```

Comment: I assume the first code snippet resides in `accessControl/users.js` and is exported via module.exports?

Comment: Also, re error logging, where are you running the app from? If a terminal, you should see the error output there.

Comment: Thanks for these hints. I edited the question. Unfortunately, no ooutput is done on the shell related to a failure.

Comment: As there's no DB to be failing, perhaps you have a syntax error in your code somewhere? Try running it through something like JSHint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(This is going to be a bit of a stab in the dark because you have not provided any details about the error...)*

<strike>Could it be that you set `session:true` but have not initialized the session middleware? Try setting `session:false`.</strike>

Actually, it looks like the problem stems from this line of code:

```
users.auth({ username: username  }, function (err, user) {
```

In the above line you are passing a custom object to `auth` but `auth` excepts a `string` object. Try replacing the above line with:

```
users.auth(username, function (err, user) {
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately, this did not fix the 500 failure.

Comment: @nesreka Ping me when you have updated the question with the **specific** error.

Comment: Somehow I cannot arrive at getting any error output. Sending the err object gives `{}` and as edited, shell output says nothing.

Comment: @nesreka Are you using express-generator to generate your template or something? Try setting the debug environment var to true. That should make the callstack surface in the error page.

Comment: I found how to log my errors by googling: http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html, I needed to add console.error(error.message) to my 500 error function. Thereby I was able to solve the problem, because it was only a minor initialization problem.